# Facebook marketing-api sandbox account

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

When I creating campaign, ad set and ad, I'm get this error:

```json
All domains need to be associated with a pixel event pair and an ad. To publish this ad, either select a new domain for your ad or configure a pixel event pair for your domain in Events Manager.: {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":3260002,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Domain Required","error_user_msg":"All domains need to be associated with a pixel event pair and an ad. To publish this ad, either select a new domain for your ad or configure a pixel event pair for your domain in Events Manager.","fbtrace_id":"AvW5I8dcvWIXI-Fe7IZuEsg"}}
```

The main problem is that we can't upload ads into sandbox ad account, because we using sandbox fb pixel and this pixel not exist in event manager.

What is possible solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue on sandbox; my workaround on sandbox was to set

```
            fbAd.Fields.conversion_domain = null;
```

and was able to create the ad.